# Unable to cpature client real IP on protocol https using Edge Stack on Digitalocean without using Proxy Protocol

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-helm, digital-ocean, clientip

I made some changes on Load Balancer to capture the real client IP as per [edge stack docs](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/emissary/latest/topics/running/ambassador-with-aws/#preserving-the-client-ip-address) and [digitalocean annotations docs](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/controllers/services/annotations.md). I made the following changes in Load Balancer:

**In Service:**

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: "false"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: http
service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-passthrough: "true"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-redirect-http-to-https: "true"
```

**In Module:**

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v3alpha1
kind: Module
metadata:
    name: ambassador
namespace: ambassador
spec:
  config:
    xff_num_trusted_hops: 1
    use_remote_address: false
```

After these changes we are able to detect client IP **"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"** on HTTP requests as shown in logs:

```
ACCESS [2022-09-13T08:43:06.434Z] "GET /v1/test/exp1 HTTP/1.1" 301 - 0 0 135 - "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "e0c33ab9-9b8b-43a1-927b-da6c324b16b2" "xyz.example.com" "-"
```

But on HTTPS we are getting client IP as **"-"**:

```
ACCESS [2022-09-13T08:43:18.619Z] "GET /v1/test/exp1 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0 2 102 63 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "de9b20c1-53bb-447b-b336-45cd532c54c2" "xyz.example.com" "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing an issue as you are using passthrough on HTTPS but as per [digital ocean docs for passthrough](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/load-balancers/how-to/ssl-passthrough/)

> SSL passthrough distributes the decryption load across the backend
> servers, but every server must have the certificate information. You
> also can’t add or modify HTTP headers, so you may lose the client’s IP
> address, port, and other information contained in the X-forwarded-*
> headers.

As suggested by DO docs we need to use a certificate so that we cannot lose HTTP headers info which includes **X-Forwarded-For** as well so the following steps are required to resolve this issue:

- First, create a certificate using this DO API: [Create Certificate](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/certificates_create).
- In response you will get certificate id something like uuid("892071a0-bb95-49bc-8021-3afd67a210bf") save it for later use.
- Made the following changes in ambassador service:

  ```
   service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: "false"
   service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: http
   service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-certificate-id: "<HERE COMES CERTIFICATE ID>"
   service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-redirect-http-to-https: "true"
  ```
- Do helm upgrade or kubectl apply to reflect changes.

That's it, enjoy.....